# Check radio buttons with link / replace content

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

first of all sorry for my english - I tried my best - hopefully you can understand what I mean. If not just ask and I try it again...

I need some help with JavaScript. I found this JavaScript function on the web and it fits verry well .

None the less there are two things i would like to change but dont know how.

**1)** The first DIV element `(ID=test)` is visible due the stylesheet. If i click on any other radio button or link the this div element `(id=test)` shouldn't be displayed any more and instead the content of the div i've clicked on should be displayed.

(Just use the code and you will see what I mean - hopefully)

**2)** Is there an opportunity that if i click on any link the corresponding radio button will be checked as well?
In this code it only displays the content if you click on the radio button. If you click on the link (which should do the same as the radio button function) it does nothing.

Hope someone could help me.

```
<html>    
<head>
      <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(d){
     var div = document.getElementById(d);
     if (showHide.div&&div!=showHide.div){
      showHide.div.style.display='none';
     }
     div.style.display = div.style.display != 'block'?'block':'none';
     showHide.div=div;
    }
    </script>     
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self">
            <input type="radio" id="input1" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide('test','input1');" checked><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHideRadio('test','input1');">Test</a></li> <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="input2" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide('question','input2');"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHideRadio('question','input2');">Questions</a></li> <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="input3" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide('more','input3');"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHideRadio('more','input3');">More</a></li> <br/>
          </form>
    </body>
    <div id="test" style="display: visible">
    <h3>This div element belongs to id="TEST" </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="question" style="display: none">
    Question
    </div>
    <div id="more" style="display: none">
    <p>Here is more Content</p>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code is more simpler for u to understand... and u have to define the function
showHideRadio()

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(){
        if (document.getElementById('input1').checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById('test').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('question').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('more').style.display='none';
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('input2').checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById('test').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('question').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('more').style.display='none';
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('input3').checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById('test').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('question').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('more').style.display='block';
        }
    }
    function showHideRadio(radioId)
    {
        document.getElementById(radioId).checked=true;
        showHide();
    }
    </script>     
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self">
            <input type="radio" id="input1" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide();" checked><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHideRadio('input1');">Test</a></li> <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="input2" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide();"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHideRadio('input2');">Questions</a></li> <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="input3" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide();"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showHideRadio('input3');">More</a></li> <br/>
          </form>
    </body>
    <div id="test" style="display: visible">
    <h3>This div element belongs to id="TEST" </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="question" style="display: none">
    Question
    </div>
    <div id="more" style="display: none">
    <p>Here is more Content</p>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you verry much for simplifying the code so that I can understand what's going on there. Helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

firstly you havent defined

```
showHideRadio
```

anywhere in your script. if you want your links to perform the same function as the radio buttons please keep the function name same... Also define what ever elements you want to inside body tag

try the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(d){
var div = document.getElementById(d);
if (showHide.div&&div!=showHide.div){
showHide.div.style.display='none';
}
div.style.display = div.style.display != 'block'?'block':'none';
showHide.div=div;
}
</script>     
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self">
<input type="radio" id="input1" name="auswahl"    onclick="javascript:showHide('test','input1');" checked><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showHide('test','input1');">Test</a></li> <br/>
 <input type="radio" id="input2" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide('question','input2');"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showHide('question','input2');">Questions</a></li> <br/>
  <input type="radio" id="input3" name="auswahl" onclick="javascript:showHide('more','input3');"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:showHide('more','input3');">More</a></li> <br/>
  </form>

<div id="test" style="display: visible">
<h3>This div element belongs to id="TEST" </h3>
</div>
<div id="question" style="display: none">
Question
</div>
<div id="more" style="display: none">
<p>Here is more Content</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

also if you want the radio button selected on link click define your function 'showHideRadio' and it to your links and in that

```
document.getElementById(yourradioid).checked = true;
```

and rest same